# A char on a variable is not being detected by '==' symbol

Tags: java, eclipse, equality, tic-tac-toe

I'm here for hours trying to solve this problem but with no success.
I'm doing a Tic Tac Toe game based on an 2D array, and i used a couple of "for" to add '-' symbols to every position of the array.
Now i'm trying to do a validation method to prevent the player from putting his 'X' on a occupied or invalid position.
When i print the board/array the '-' is there on every position, but when i try to do an "if the position has '-' it's a valid movement", the code keeps returning that there's no '-' there, even if it has.
The "jog" and "tab" its because i'm using different class.
Also my debug doesn't shows any variable from the first println on, i dont know why.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    Tabuleiro tab = new Tabuleiro();
    Jogador jog = new Jogador();
    Computador comp = new Computador();
    
    tab.inicializarTabuleiro();
    tab.mostraTabuleiro();
    
    System.out.println("Bem vindo ao Jogo da Velha!");
    System.out.println("Escolha a dificuldade desejada de 1 a 3");
    Scanner dificuldade = new Scanner(System.in);
    if (dificuldade.nextInt() == 1){

        for (int i = 1; i <= 9; i++){
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Escolha uma posição(1-9)");
            int jogada = scan.nextInt();
            jog.converteJogada(jogada); //this code converts int from keyboard to a position on array
            jog.verificaJogada(jogada); //this code is the problem
            System.out.println(jog.row); //used this to check if position is correct, it is
            System.out.println(jog.col);//same from above
            System.out.println(tab.mat[jog.row][jog.col]); //used to print the position to see if '-' it was there, it was
            System.out.println(jog.valid); //to see if '-' is being confirmed or not
    }
```

---

```
public class Tabuleiro {
        
public Tabuleiro(){
}

public char mat[][] = new char[3][3];

public void inicializarTabuleiro(){
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
            mat[i][j] = '-';
        }
    }
}

public void mostraTabuleiro(){
    System.out.println("-------------");
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        System.out.print("| ");
        for (int j = 0;j < 3; j++){
            System.out.print(mat[i][j] + " | ");
        }   
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("-------------");
    }
    }
}
```

---

```
public class Jogador{

public Jogador(){
}

public Jogador(int linha, int coluna, boolean valid) {
    this.linha = linha;
    this.coluna = coluna;
    this.valid = valid;
}

Tabuleiro tab = new Tabuleiro();
Jogo jog = new Jogo();

public int linha;
public int coluna;
public boolean valid;
public char nulo;

public void converteJogada(int jogada){
    switch(jogada){
    case 1:
        row = 0;
        col = 0;
        break;
    case 2:
        row = 0;
        col = 1;
        break; 
    case 3:
        row = 0;
        col = 2;
        break;
    case 4:
        row = 1;
        col = 0;
        break;
    case 5:
        row = 1;
        col = 1;
        break;
    case 6:
        row = 1;
        col = 2;
        break;
    case 7:
        row = 2;
        col = 0;
        break;
    case 8:
        row = 2;
        col = 1;
        break;
    case 9:
        row = 2;
        col = 2;
        break;
        default:
            break;}
} 
    
public void verificaJogada(int jogada){
    if ((jogada >= 0 && jogada <= 9) && (tab.mat[row][col] == '-')){
    valid = true;
    }
    else {
        valid = false;
    }
```

}

**PROBLEM SOLVED** Because of poor lessons i was having the bad practice to instance the others classes on every class. This made my code have a lot of arrays and not just one were my code was referencing to. So my main array(e.g. the Tabuleiro) was initialized with the '-' but there was an instance of Tabuleiro class on Jogador class, the array of this instance was not being initialized and that was the array my "verificaJogada" was testing. Thanks for the answers that helped me achieve this.

Comment: What is your `Tabuleiro` class definition, particularly the `mat` field and `inicializarTabuleiro()` method?

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that we can run and debug for ourselves.  As it stands, we can't tell you what the problem is ... except that it is most likely in code that you haven't shown us.

Comment: Specifically, what's datatype is the 2D array supposed to be holding? If it's supposed to have String and you're using == to compare to a char, you're going to have a lot of problems.

Comment: (If it was a String array, comparing with a `char` would be a compilation error ...)

Comment: What does `converteJogada(jogada)` do? You can't change anything about that primitive `int` variable and I don't see the `row` or `col` variables anywhere.  You need to post more code.

Comment: I updated the code with what you asked. I'm sorry for not posting before, thought it would be tiresome

Comment: Do note that there are 3 different classes. "Jogo", "Tabuleiro" and "Jogador". The particular error is on Jogador class

Comment: Update here: I just took "inicializarTabuleiro()" method off from the Tabuleiro class and put on my main and the problem was solved. I really don't have any clue why but....

Comment: Have you ran through your code with a debugger?

Comment: I just did. I was having problems with using because for some reason i had to search for the main on debugger, instead of instantly being taken to there(like on teacher pc). But i discovered the problem. My teacher taught us that we should always instance another class when using its methods. But that made my code have a lot of different arrays so different methods were consulting different arrays... :(

Answer (score 1):

The cause of your problems is that you have declared the class `Jogador` to have a `Tabuleiro` field like this:

```
Tabuleiro tab = new Tabuleiro();
```

and that is what `Jogador.verificaJogada` is testing.  But that is a *different* `Tabuleiro` instance to the one that you initialized in your `main` method.

Clearly `verificaJogada` needs to be testing the `Tabuleiro` that you created and initialized in `main`.

---

> How can i reference the instance of main there then?

You pass the `Tabuleiro` instance created in `main` as a parameter:

- either a parameter to the constructor for `Jogador` (which you can then assign to the `Jogador.tab` field)
- or a parameter to the `verificaJogada` method.

> I thought i had to make an instance of every class on every class for this to work..

I don't know where you got that idea from.  Each time you write `new Tabuleiro()`, you are creating a new `Tabuleiro` instance that is distinct from all previously created instances.

The Java `new` operator **always** creates a new instance<sup>1</sup>.  It **never** returns an instance that was created earlier.

---

<sup>1 - ... or throws an exception.</sup>

Comment: Just help me one more time, please? How can i reference the instance of main there then? I thought i had to make an instance of every class on every class for this to work..